# Communication with Openssl epoll server to multiple clients simultaneously in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, sockets, ssl, openssl

I have an SSL server (code listed below) connecting to multiple SSL client. I am using a single context and the initialization is

```
SSL_CTX *ctx;
SSL *ssl[MAXEVENTS];
SSL_library_init();
ctx = InitServerCTX();        // initialize SSL
...
...
```

Then I have the following piece of code

```
ssl[i] = SSL_new(ctx);           // get new SSL state with context
SSL_set_fd(ssl[i], infd);        // set connection socket to SSL state
```

Then I perform `SSL_accept(ssl[i])`.

All this is being performed using epoll (edge trigger mode). I have modified the example in https://banu.com/blog/2/how-to-use-epoll-a-complete-example-in-c/ to use SSL by referring to  https://www.cs.utah.edu/~swalton/listings/articles/ssl_server.c as a reference

The logic for this is

```
 events = new epoll_event[MAXEVENTS * sizeof event];

 // The event loop
 while (true)
 {
    int n, i;

    n = epoll_wait (efd, events, MAXEVENTS, -1);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if ((events[i].events & EPOLLERR) ||
                (events[i].events & EPOLLHUP) ||
                (!(events[i].events & EPOLLIN)))
        {
            // An error has occured on this fd, or the socket is not
            // ready for reading (why were we notified then?)
            fprintf (stderr, "epoll error\n");
            close (events[i].data.fd);
            continue;
        } else if (sfd == events[i].data.fd) {
            // We have a notification on the listening socket, which
            // means one or more incoming connections.
            while (1)
            {

                struct sockaddr in_addr;
                socklen_t in_len;
                int infd;
                char hbuf[NI_MAXHOST], sbuf[NI_MAXSERV];

                in_len = sizeof in_addr;
                infd = accept (sfd, &in_addr, &in_len);
                if (infd == -1)
                {
                    if ((errno == EAGAIN) ||(errno == EWOULDBLOCK)) {
                        // We have processed all incoming
                        // connections.
                        break;
                    } else {
                        perror ("accept");
                        break;
                    }
                }

                s = getnameinfo (&in_addr, in_len,
                                 hbuf, sizeof hbuf,
                                 sbuf, sizeof sbuf,
                                 NI_NUMERICHOST | NI_NUMERICSERV);
                if (s == 0) {
                    printf("Accepted connection on descriptor %d "
                           "(host=%s, port=%s)\n", infd, hbuf, sbuf);
                }


    ssl[i] = SSL_new(ctx);           // get new SSL state with context
    SSL_set_fd(ssl[i], infd);        // set connection socket to SSL state

    int ret;
    if ( (ret=SSL_accept(ssl[i])) == FAIL ) {    // do SSL-protocol accept
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    printf("Performing exchange Error 1.\n");
    int error = SSL_get_error(ssl[i], 0);

    //TODO A retry timer or retry counter. Cannot keep retrying perpetually.
    if (ret <=0 && (error == SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ)) {
        //Need to wait until socket is readable. Take action?
        //LOG the reason here
        perror ("Need to wait until socket is readable.");
    } else if (ret <=0 && (error == SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE)) {
        //Need to wait until socket is writable. Take action?
        //LOG the reason here
        perror ("Need to wait until socket is writable.");
    } else {
        //LOG the reason here
        perror ("Need to wait until socket is ready.");
    }
    shutdown (infd, 2);
    SSL_free (ssl[i]);
    continue;
    }
    // Make the incoming socket non-blocking and add it to the
    // list of fds to monitor.
    s = SocketNonBlocking (infd);
    if (s == -1) {
    abort ();
    }
    event.data.fd = infd;
    event.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET | EPOLLHUP;
    s = epoll_ctl (efd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, infd, &event);
    if (s == -1) {
    perror ("epoll_ctl");
    abort ();
    }
}
continue;
```

Now,

```
    while (1)
    {
        ssize_t count;
        char buf[1024];
        char reply[1024];

        printf("Performing exchange.\n");
        const char* HTMLecho="<html><body><pre>%s</pre></body></html>\n\n";

        ShowCerts(ssl[i]);        // get any certificates
        count = SSL_read(ssl[i], buf, sizeof(buf)); // get request
        int32_t ssl_error = SSL_get_error (ssl[i], count);
        switch (ssl_error) {
         case SSL_ERROR_NONE: 
                    printf("SSL_ERROR_NONE\n");
                    break;
         case SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:
                    printf("SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ\n");
                    break;
         case SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE:
                    printf("SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE\n");
                    break;
         case SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN:
                    printf("SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN\n");  
                    break;
         default:
                    break;
         }

        if (( count > 0 ) )
        {
            buf[count] = 0;
            printf("count > 0 Client msg: \"%s\"\n", buf);
            sprintf(reply, HTMLecho, buf);   // construct reply
            SSL_write(ssl[i], reply, strlen(reply)); // send reply
        } else if ((count < 0)  ){
            printf("count < 0 \n");
            if (errno != EAGAIN)
            {
                printf("count < 0 errno != EAGAIN \n");
                perror ("read");
                done = 1;
            }
            break;
        } else if (count==0){
            ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
            epoll_ctl(efd, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, events[i].data.fd, NULL);
            printf("count == 0 Client Disconnected.\n");
            done = 1;
            break;
        }

    }
    if (done)
    {
        printf("Freeing data.\n");
        int sd = SSL_get_fd(ssl[i]);
        SSL_free(ssl[i]);         // release SSL state
        close(sd);          // close connection
        //close (events[i].data.fd);
    }
   }
```

This works fine for one server - one client. But the moment I try to connect two clients, the client that connected last is the only one that receives the data. The client that was connected before just keeps hanging without any activity.

**UPDATE**
I found that there is some indexing issue going on here. The value of the variable `i` from the epoll example is not corresponding to what I think it should be corresponding. I tried connecting two clients and I had thought initially the `i` should have incremented for second client but it is not the case. It still stays `0`.

Comment: Can you show the logic where you add the connected sockets to epoll and the `epoll_wait` code?

Comment: @Prabhu I have updated the question to show the logic. This logic is very similar to epoll example link above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I solved the issue. My problem stemmed from incorrect indexing. I was relying on the variable `i` that did not behave the way I expected. (see update in my question)

First I declare `std::map<int,SSL*> sslPairMap;`

Then I insert the successful fd and SSL accept into a std::map in C++. In C, one can use struct based pairing. There is one example here https://github.com/dCache/dcap/blob/b432bd322f0c1cf3e5c6a561845899eec3acad1e/plugins/ssl/sslTunnel.c

```
                //(c) 2014 enthusiasticgeek for stack overflow

                sslPairMap.insert(std::pair<int,SSL*>(infd, ssl));

                // Make the incoming socket non-blocking and add it to the
                // list of fds to monitor.
                s = AibSocketNonBlocking (infd);
                if (s == -1) {
                    abort ();
                }
                aibevent.data.fd = infd;
                aibevent.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET | EPOLLHUP;
                s = epoll_ctl (efd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, infd, &aibevent);
                if (s == -1) {
                    perror ("epoll_ctl");
                    abort ();
                }
```

After this I simply retrieve the SSL* from the map which ensures I do not change index inadvertently. std::map saves the day

```
           //(c) 2014 enthusiasticgeek for stack overflow
           while (1)
            {
                ssize_t count;
                char buf[1024];
                char reply[1024];

                printf("Performing exchange where i = %d.\n",i);
                const char* HTMLecho="<html><body><pre>%s</pre></body></html>\n\n";

                ShowCerts(sslPairMap[aibevents[i].data.fd]);        // get any certificate

                count = SSL_read(sslPairMap[aibevents[i].data.fd], buf, sizeof(buf)); // get request
                ssl_error = SSL_get_error (sslPairMap[aibevents[i].data.fd], count);
                switch (ssl_error) {
                case SSL_ERROR_NONE: 
                            printf("SSL_ERROR_NONE\n");
                            break;
                case SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:
                            printf("SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ\n");
                            break;
                case SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE:
                            printf("SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE\n");
                            break;
                case SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN:
                            printf("SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN\n");  
                            break;
                default:
                            break;
                 }

                if (( count > 0 ) )
                {
                    buf[count] = 0;
                    printf("count > 0 Client msg: \"%s\"\n", buf);
                    sprintf(reply, HTMLecho, buf);   // construct reply
                    SSL_write(sslPairMap[aibevents[i].data.fd], reply, strlen(reply)); // send reply
                    break;
                } else if ((count < 0)  ){
                    printf("count < 0 \n");
                    if (errno != EAGAIN)
                    {
                        printf("count < 0 errno != EAGAIN \n");
                        perror ("read");
                        done = 1;
                    }
                    break;
                } else if (count==0){
                    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
                    epoll_ctl(efd, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, aibevents[i].data.fd, NULL);
                    printf("count == 0 Client Disconnected.\n");
                    done = 1;
                    break;
                }

            }
            if (done)
            {
                printf("Freeing data.\n");
                int sd = SSL_get_fd(sslPairMap[aibevents[i].data.fd]);
                if(ssl_error == SSL_ERROR_NONE){
                   SSL_shutdown(sslPairMap[aibevents[i].data.fd]);
                }
                SSL_free(sslPairMap[aibevents[i].data.fd]);         // release SSL state
                close(sd);          // close connection
                //close (aibevents[i].data.fd);
                erase_from_map(sslPairMap, aibevents[i].data.fd);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this, another way to go about it is to store the `SSL*` pointer in the event data itself:

```
events[i].data.u64 = (long long)ssl;
```

And when you need to read/write from it:

```
auto ssl = (SSL*)events[i].data.u64;
SSL_read(ssl, someBuffer, sizeof(someBuffer));
```

For example.